# Subscribe showing deprecated Angular

Tags: angular, deprecated, subscribe

I am trying to code a movie app and I am getting this message:

"'(next?: ((value: any) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription' is deprecated.ts(6385)
Observable.d.ts(51, 9): The declaration was marked as deprecated here."

This is what my code looks like:

```
registerUser(): void {
    this.fetchApiData.userRegistration(this.userData).subscribe((result) => {
      // Logic for a successful user registration goes here! (To be implemented)
      this.dialogRef.close(); // This will close the modal on success!
      this.snackBar.open(result, 'OK', {
        duration: 2000
      });
    }, (result) => {
```

Can someone please help and thanks!

I am trying to make subscribe work.

Answer (score 2):

Deprecation warning you are seeing is related to the usage of the subscribe() method. In newer versions of RxJS, the signature of the subscribe() method has changed, and the old signature is now marked as deprecated.

updated code:

```
registerUser(): void {
  this.fetchApiData.userRegistration(this.userData).subscribe({
    next: (result) => {
      // Logic for a successful user registration goes here! (To be implemented)
      this.dialogRef.close(); // This will close the modal on success!
      this.snackBar.open(result, 'OK', {
        duration: 2000
      });
    },
    error: (error) => {
      // Handle error cases
    },
    complete: () => {
      // Handle completion cases
    }
  });
}
```

subscribe() method now accepts an object as an argument with properties next, error, and complete. You can provide the corresponding functions for each property to handle the next value, errors, and completion of the observable.

hope it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of `subscribe` method accepts object parameter with 3 optional fields:

```
export interface Observer<T> {
  next: (value: T) => void;
  error: (err: any) => void;
  complete: () => void;
}
```

So `.subscribe(result => ...)` should be replaced with `.subscribe({next: (result) => ...})`